# POST log replay using access.log

Tags: post, logging, jmeter, httprequest, stress-testing

I'm looking for stress test tool which can replay **POST log from access.log file**.
And also, I want to see performance graph and some values.

Is there any recommended tool? or any recommended way using specific tool..?
(I already tested with Jmeter(v5.4.1), But Jmeter didn't support sending request_body using "access log sampler".)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Standard [TCLogParser](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/accesslog/TCLogParser.java) will only generate [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), it won't store request body even if it's present in the access log.

So if you want to continue with JMeter you will have to implement your own variant of [LogParser](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/accesslog/LogParser.java) like it's described in [The JMeter Access Log Sampler - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-access-log-sampler-a-guide) article.

You may also be interested [How to write a plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) guide.